# Order by case statement with conditions and multiple sort columns and else

Tags: sql, sql-order-by

I would like to be able to sort using different columns dependent on which parameter is selected.
I can get it to work for single columns but are struggling with multiple.
Any help would be much appreciated.

```
ORDER BY
CASE WHEN @a like '%apples%' or @a like '%onions%' then
DeliveryScheduleItems.DropSequence, 
DeliveryAddresses.PostalCode,
Customers.CustomerId
Else
DeliverySchedules.DeliveryDate,
DeliveryAddresses.PostalCode,
Customers.CustomerId
End
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
ORDER BY
CASE 
WHEN @a like '%apples%' or @a like '%onions%' then
DeliveryScheduleItems.DropSequence, 
DeliveryAddresses.PostalCode,
Customers.CustomerId
WHEN @a not like '%apples%' AND @a not like '%onions%' then
DeliverySchedules.DeliveryDate,
DeliveryAddresses.PostalCode,
Customers.CustomerId
End
```

Comment: Many thanks for your response, this works for a single sort column, but not for multiple. Incorrect syntax near ','

Answer (score 0):

You need multiple conditions:

```
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN @a like '%apples%' or @a like '%onions%'
               THEN DeliveryScheduleItems.DropSequence
          END),
         (CASE WHEN @a like '%apples%' or @a like '%onions%'
               THEN NULL
               ELSE DeliverySchedules.DeliveryDate
          END),
         DeliveryAddresses.PostalCode,
         Customers.CustomerId
```

Note the use of two `CASE` expressions for the two different columns. Presumably `DeliveryDate` and `DropSequence` have different types.  It is better to order them separately.